# Can't install MAYO theme

Tags: theming, 8

After installing MAYO, I refresh my main site and get this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactory::getEditable() in /var/www/fs1/38/[user name]/public_html/themes/mayo/mayo.theme on line 331

Re-installing didn't help. I can't figure for the life of me what I am doing wrong.

Could anybody help, please?

Comment: That class and method both [exist for 8.0.x, 8.1.x and 8.2.x](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21ConfigFactory.php/function/ConfigFactory%3A%3AgetEditable/8.2.x), so you possibly have some missing files in your Drupal installation

Comment: Did you check that the class exists in your core directory?

Comment: Thank you both for helping :)
It actually was messed up Drupal installation (I know, I said I did re-intallation, but somehow I made a plunder of that one too).
After I did another installation, everything worked like a dream.
Again, thank you both very much for helping a green beginner :)